# WCF On Azure size issues

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, web-config, webclient

I have found posts that are not far from my problem, and still haven't been able to resolve this so please don't say it's duplicate and try to help.

I have a web service hosted on Azure.

When calling a specific method with large (not that large) amount of data i get a general error: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

I know this is size related since the request has one large string in it, when its around 4.5 MB all works well, when the request is around 5 MB or above the request fails with the general error.

The web.config is on maximum size as far as i know:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myWebHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"  >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This is how the method is declared:

```
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/PublishDataItems")]
        ServerRespones PublishDataItems(DataItemRequest Request);
```

And this is how i call the method from the client:

```
WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
            proxy.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DataItemRequest));
            ser.WriteObject(ms, myRequest);
            byte[] data = proxy.UploadData(URL + "PublishDataItems", "POST", ms.ToArray());
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ServerRespones));
            var result = obj.ReadObject(stream) as ServerRespones;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing a load balancer time out.  Not many details on duration before connections are dropped but your issue may be related to request duration rather than size.  Take a look at [this MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/12/windows-azure-load-balancer-timeout-details.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The default WCF transfer mode is Buffered, change to stream mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms733742.aspx